# Why doesn't the Status Report page show any information?

Tags: 9

I've just done an upgrade of my site from Drupal 8.9.16 to Drupal 9.2.6. Everything looks fine but when I go to /admin/reports/status there is no information as per the screenshot. I've never come across this before, can anyone help?

I cleared the cache multiple times, ran Cron, without any effect.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I had this one ages ago, something's telling me it was a problem with the version of PHP, Apache or MySQL but I can't quite remember

Comment: Bingo @Clive you are spot on! It was PHP set to 7.2 not 7.4. Big thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the PHP version on the server was set to 7.2 when it should have been 7.3 or higher.